# Testing Annotation based RequestInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I wanted to do so custom logic(Record the request and response) on some routes. Based on some research I came decided to use AnnotationBased RequestInterceptor. This is my code for interceptor.

```
public class CustomInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
@Override
public void afterCompletion(final HttpServletRequest request,
                            final HttpServletResponse response,
                            final Object handler,
                            final Exception ex) {
     if (handler != null && handler instanceof  HandlerMethod) {
        HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
        CustomRecord annotation = AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(handlerMethod.getMethod(), CustomRecord.class);
        if (annotation != null) {
              // Record Request and Response in a File.
        }
}
```

Now this class is working as expected but I was unable to unit test this function.

- I first thought of trying a creating an HandlerMethod Object but I
  did not get anywhere.
- Second I tried to use PowerMokito. This was my test code:

  ```
  @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
  @PrepareForTest(CustomInterceptor.class)
  @PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
  public class CustomInterceptorTest {
  @Test
  public void restAnnotationRecording_negetivecase() {
    HandlerMethod mockHandler = mock(HandlerMethod.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(AnnotationUtils.class);
    when(AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(mockHandler.getMethod(), 
         CustomRecord.class).thenReturn(null);
    // Verify file is not saved
  }
   // A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() methodcannot be saved.
  @Test
  public void restAnnotationRecording_happycase() {
      HandlerMethod mockHandler = mock(HandlerMethod.class);
      PowerMockito.mockStatic(AnnotationUtils.class);
      when(AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(mockHandler.getMethod(), CustomRecord.class).thenReturn(mockAnnotation);
      // Verify file is saved
  }
  }
  ```

  - This gives an Error A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies  with doReturn|Throw() family of methods.

I wanted to check if there is any method to test the Interceptor. I am a newbie in Java, thanks for help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can easily create your own `HandlerMethod` without mocking. There's a [constructor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethod.html#HandlerMethod-java.lang.Object-java.lang.reflect.Method-) that accepts an Object (the controller) and a `Method` (the controller method). The easiest way to get a `Method` is to simply call `Class.getMethod()`. What you want to do is just create a dummy controller class, and then use that class to get the method. For example

```
class TestController {
    @Custom
    public void testMethod() {}
}

Method method = TestController.class.getMethod("testMethod");
TestController controller = new TestController();
HandlerMethod handlerMethod = new HandlerMethod(controller, method);

Custom annotation = handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(Custom.class);
```

It's that easy. Below is a complete test.

```
public class HandlerInterceptorTest {

    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    private @interface Custom {
    }

    private static class MyHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, Object handler) {
            if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
                HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
                Custom annotation = handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(Custom.class);
                if (annotation != null) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static class TestController {
        @Custom
        public void testMethodWithAnnotation() {}

        public void testMethodWithoutAnnotation() {}
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethodWithAnnotation() throws Exception {
        Method method = TestController.class.getMethod("testMethodWithAnnotation");
        TestController controller = new TestController();
        HandlerMethod handlerMethod = new HandlerMethod(controller, method);

        MyHandlerInterceptor interceptor = new MyHandlerInterceptor();
        boolean result = interceptor.preHandle(null, null, handlerMethod);

        assertTrue(result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethodWithoutAnnotation() throws Exception {
        Method method = TestController.class.getMethod("testMethodWithoutAnnotation");
        TestController controller = new TestController();
        HandlerMethod handlerMethod = new HandlerMethod(controller, method);

        MyHandlerInterceptor interceptor = new MyHandlerInterceptor();
        boolean result = interceptor.preHandle(null, null, handlerMethod);

        assertFalse(result);
    }
}
```